# RDP to a fixed IP VPS

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, remote-desktop

I can't connect to a remote VPS with fixed IP from win 10 home. I can access the same from win 8 pro. I can't ping from either. I am getting the generic remote desktop can't connect error message. On the server I can see a lot of Logon Audit Failures in the event viewer, failure reason is Unknown username or bad password. But at the client it is not even asking for a password.

The win 8 pro pc has a local user, whereas the win 10 home PC is logged in with windows live account.

Comment: Does the RDP client show the text "Saved credentials will be used" or similar? Can you connect from `mstsc /public`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.